# AKS Service deployment done and can´t reach external IPs

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I've created a Kubernetes cluster in Azure using the following Terraform

```
# Locals block for hardcoded names
locals {
  backend_address_pool_name      = "appgateway-beap"
  frontend_port_name             = "appgateway-feport"
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "appgateway-feip"
  http_setting_name              = "appgateway-be-htst"
  listener_name                  = "appgateway-httplstn"
  request_routing_rule_name      = "appgateway-rqrt"
  app_gateway_subnet_name        = "appgateway-subnet"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "aks-subnet" {
  name                 = "aks-subnet"
  virtual_network_name = "np-dat-spoke-vnet"
  resource_group_name  = "ipz12-dat-np-connect-rg"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "appgateway-subnet" {
  name                 = "appgateway-subnet"
  virtual_network_name = "np-dat-spoke-vnet"
  resource_group_name  = "ipz12-dat-np-connect-rg"
}

# Create Resource Group for Kubernetes Cluster
module "resource_group_kubernetes_cluster" {
  source                  = "./modules/resource_group"
  count                   = var.enable_kubernetes == true ? 1 : 0
  #name_override          = "rg-aks-spoke-dev-westus3-001"
  app_or_service_name     = "aks"                                   # var.app_or_service_name
  subscription_type       = var.subscription_type                   # "spoke"   
  environment             = var.environment                         # "dev"    
  location                = var.location                            # "westus3"
  instance_number         = var.instance_number                     # "001"    
  tags                    = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "identity_uami" {
  location            = var.location
  name                = "appgw-uami"
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group_kubernetes_cluster[0].name
}

# Application Gateway Public Ip 
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
  name                = "publicIp1"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group_kubernetes_cluster[0].name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network" {
  name                = var.app_gateway_name
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group_kubernetes_cluster[0].name
  location            = var.location

  sku {
    name     = var.app_gateway_sku
    tier     = "Standard_v2"
    capacity = 2
  }

  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [
      azurerm_user_assigned_identity.identity_uami.id
    ]
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "appGatewayIpConfig"
    subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.appgateway-subnet.id
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = local.frontend_port_name
    port = 80
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = "httpsPort"
    port = 443
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.test.id
  }

  backend_address_pool {
    name = local.backend_address_pool_name
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = local.http_setting_name
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 1
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = local.listener_name
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = local.frontend_port_name
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = local.request_routing_rule_name
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = local.listener_name
    backend_address_pool_name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name
    priority                   = 100
  }

  tags = var.tags

  depends_on = [azurerm_public_ip.test]

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      backend_address_pool,
      backend_http_settings,
      request_routing_rule,
      http_listener,
      probe,
      tags,
      frontend_port
    ]
  }
}

# Create the Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) Cluster
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "kubernetes_cluster" {
  count                         = var.enable_kubernetes == true ? 1 : 0
  name                          = "aks-prjx-${var.subscription_type}-${var.environment}-${var.location}-${var.instance_number}"    
  location                      = var.location
  resource_group_name           = module.resource_group_kubernetes_cluster[0].name  # "rg-aks-spoke-dev-westus3-001"
  dns_prefix                    = "dns-aks-prjx-${var.subscription_type}-${var.environment}-${var.location}-${var.instance_number}" #"dns-prjxcluster"
  private_cluster_enabled       = false
  local_account_disabled        = true

  default_node_pool {
    name                        = "npprjx${var.subscription_type}" #"prjxsyspool" # NOTE: "name must start with a lowercase letter, have max length of 12, and only have characters a-z0-9."
    vm_size                     = "Standard_B8ms"
    vnet_subnet_id              = data.azurerm_subnet.aks-subnet.id
    # zones                     = ["1", "2", "3"]
    enable_auto_scaling         = true
    max_count                   = 3
    min_count                   = 1
    # node_count                = 3
    os_disk_size_gb             = 50
    type                        = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    enable_node_public_ip       = false
    enable_host_encryption      = false

    node_labels = {
      "node_pool_type"          = "npprjx${var.subscription_type}"
      "node_pool_os"            = "linux"
      "environment"             = "${var.environment}"
      "app"                     = "prjx_${var.subscription_type}_app"
    }
    tags = var.tags
  }

  ingress_application_gateway {
    gateway_id = azurerm_application_gateway.network.id
  }

  # Enabled the cluster configuration to the Azure kubernets with RBAC
  azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control { 
    managed                     = true
    admin_group_object_ids      = var.active_directory_role_based_access_control_admin_group_object_ids
    azure_rbac_enabled          = true #false
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin              = "azure"
    network_policy              = "azure"
    outbound_type               = "userDefinedRouting"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }  

  oms_agent {
    log_analytics_workspace_id  = module.log_analytics_workspace[0].id
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "20m"
    delete = "20m"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_application_gateway.network
  ]
}
```

and provided the necessary permissions

```
# Get the AKS Agent Pool SystemAssigned Identity
data "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "aks-identity" {
  name                = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes_cluster[0].name}-agentpool"
  resource_group_name = "MC_${module.resource_group_kubernetes_cluster[0].name}_aks-prjx-spoke-dev-eastus-001_eastus"
}

# Get the AKS SystemAssigned Identity
data "azuread_service_principal" "aks-sp" {
  display_name  = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes_cluster[0].name
}

# Provide ACR Pull permission to AKS SystemAssigned Identity
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "acrpull_role" {
  scope                            = module.container_registry[0].id
  role_definition_name             = "AcrPull"
  principal_id                     = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.aks-identity.principal_id
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true

  depends_on                       = [
    data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.aks-identity
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aks_id_network_contributor_subnet" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subnet.aks-subnet.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.aks-identity.principal_id

  depends_on = [data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.aks-identity]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "akssp_network_contributor_subnet" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subnet.aks-subnet.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_service_principal.aks-sp.object_id

  depends_on = [data.azuread_service_principal.aks-sp]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aks_id_contributor_agw" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subnet.appgateway-subnet.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.aks-identity.principal_id

  depends_on = [data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.aks-identity]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "akssp_contributor_agw" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subnet.appgateway-subnet.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_service_principal.aks-sp.object_id

  depends_on = [data.azuread_service_principal.aks-sp]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aks_ingressid_contributor_on_agw" {
  scope                            = azurerm_application_gateway.network.id
  role_definition_name             = "Contributor"
  principal_id                     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes_cluster[0].ingress_application_gateway[0].ingress_application_gateway_identity[0].object_id
  depends_on                       = [azurerm_application_gateway.network,azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes_cluster]
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aks_ingressid_contributor_on_uami" {
  scope                            = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.identity_uami.id
  role_definition_name             = "Contributor"
  principal_id                     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes_cluster[0].ingress_application_gateway[0].ingress_application_gateway_identity[0].object_id
  depends_on                       = [azurerm_application_gateway.network,azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes_cluster]
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "uami_contributor_on_agw" {
  scope                            = azurerm_application_gateway.network.id
  role_definition_name             = "Contributor"
  principal_id                     = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.identity_uami.principal_id
  depends_on                       = [azurerm_application_gateway.network,azurerm_user_assigned_identity.identity_uami]
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
}
```

and deployed the below mentioned application

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aks-helloworld 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: aks-helloworld-two
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aks-helloworld-two
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: aks-helloworld-two
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aks-helloworld:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: TITLE
          value: "AKS Ingress Demo"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: aks-helloworld 
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: aks-helloworld-two
```

[image]

External IP got assigned

[image]

however I am not able to access the External IP

[image]

**Note:** I have not deployed any Ingress controller separately like mentioned in the [Microsoft Article](https://NAMESPACE=ingress-basic%20%20helm%20repo%20add%20ingress-nginx%20https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx%20helm%20repo%20update%20%20helm%20install%20ingress-nginx%20ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx%20%5C%20%20%20--create-namespace%20%5C%20%20%20--namespace%20$NAMESPACE%20%5C%20%20%20--set%20controller.service.annotations.%22service%5C.beta%5C.kubernetes%5C.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path%22=/healthz) as I am not sure this is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create Kubernetes Service Cluster with Application Gateway:**

Follow the [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75154385/aks-loadbalancer-external-ip-stuck-on-pending/75159961#75159961)  to create **Kubernetes Service Cluster** with **Ingress Application Gateway**.

If you are unable to access your application using external Load balancer IP after deployment in **Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)**, Verify the below setting in **AKS Cluster**.

1.check the status of the load balancer using the below cmd.

```
kubectl get service <your service name>
```

Make sure that the **External -IP** field is not set to **Pending** state.

[image]

2. Verify the security group associated with the load balancer. Make sure that the security group allows traffic on the desired port.

Kindly follow the below steps to check **NSG Security** rules in **AKS** cluster.

**Go to Azure Portal > Kubernetes services > Select your Kubernetes services> Properties > Select your resource group under Infrastructure resource group > overview > Select your NSG Group.**

[image]

I have disabled inbound **http** rule in **Network Security Group** for testing, got the same error.

[image]

Application status, once disable the **Port** 80 in **NSG**.

[image]

3. check the routing rules on your virtual network. Make sure that traffic is being forwarded from the load balancer.

[image]