# Starting an AKS cluster with Terraform

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform

I am trying to use Terraform to create an AKS cluster, then deploy a basic loadbalacer and finally get Nginx-ingress-controller to use the Loadbalancer.

Here is my Terraform code so far,

```
# Set default name prefix
variable "name_prefix" {
  default = "Dev"
}

# Set default location
variable "location" {
  default = "australiacentral"
}

# Create Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks_rg" {
  name     = "${var.name_prefix}-rg"
  location = var.location
}

# Managed Cluster resource group
#export MC_RESOURCE_GROUP=MC_${RESOURCE_GROUP}_${AKS_CLUSTER}_${LOCATION}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "dk_dev_cluster" {
  name                = var.name_prefix
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  dns_prefix = "Dev"
  kubernetes_version = "1.25.5"
  # Create a basic load-balancer to lower costs
  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
    load_balancer_sku = "basic"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name    = lower("${var.name_prefix}nodep")
    vm_size = "Standard_B2s"
    node_count = 1
    enable_auto_scaling = false
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "lb_pub_ip" {
  name                = "${var.name_prefix}-lb-ip"
  location            = var.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku = "Basic"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.dk_dev_cluster.node_resource_group
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "aks_lb" {
  name                = "${var.name_prefix}-lb"
  sku                 = "Basic"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.dk_dev_cluster.node_resource_group
  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "PublicIPAddress"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.lb_pub_ip.id
  }
}

output "client_certificate" {
  value     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.dk_dev_cluster.kube_config.0.client_certificate
  sensitive = true
}

output "kube_config" {
  value = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.dk_dev_cluster.kube_config_raw

  sensitive = true
}

# Create a kubeconfig file that can be added to/replace ~/.kube/config
resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  depends_on   = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.dk_dev_cluster]
  filename     = "kubeconfig"
  content      = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.dk_dev_cluster.kube_config_raw
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = local_file.kubeconfig.filename
  config_context = "Dev"
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "nginx_namespace" {
  metadata {
    name = "nginx-ingress"
  }
  depends_on = [local_file.kubeconfig]
}

provider "helm" {
}

resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  name       = "nginx-ingress-controller"

  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"
  version    = "4.5.2"
  namespace = kubernetes_namespace.nginx_namespace.id

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.loadBalancerIP"
    value = azurerm_public_ip.lb_pub_ip.ip_address
  }
}
```

When the look at services in the `nginx-ingress` namespace the LoadBalacer external IP is stuck as `<pending>`

```
NAME                                                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
nginx-ingress-controller-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.60.72    <pending>     80:32183/TCP,443:31864/TCP   27s
```

`kubectl get events`:

```
41s         Warning   SyncLoadBalancerFailed   service/nginx-ingress-controller-ingress-nginx-controller                 Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: instance not found
```

From my understanding this is because nginx cannot reach the load balancer as the AKS cluster is in the non Managed resource group, while the LB is in the Manged resource group. I cannot figure out a way to deploy them into the same resource group.

Please let me know how I can allow Nginx to connect to the Loadbalancer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this without adding my own Service Principal.

To provision a AKS cluster with a Standard LB then get Nginx to use it, I used the following Terraform:

```
# Set default name prefix
variable "name_prefix" {
  default = "Dev"
}

# Set default location
variable "location" {
  default = "australiacentral"
}

# Create Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks_rg" {
  name     = "${var.name_prefix}-rg"
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "dk_dev_cluster" {
  name                = var.name_prefix
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "Dev"
  kubernetes_version  = "1.25.5"
  # Create a basic load-balancer to lower costs
  network_profile {
    network_plugin    = "kubenet"
    load_balancer_sku = "standard"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name                = lower("${var.name_prefix}nodep")
    vm_size             = "Standard_B2s"
    node_count          = 1
    enable_auto_scaling = false
    os_sku              = "CBLMariner"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
  sku_tier = "Free"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "lb_pub_ip" {
  name                = "${var.name_prefix}-lb-ip"
  location            = var.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.dk_dev_cluster.node_resource_group
}

output "client_certificate" {
  value     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.dk_dev_cluster.kube_config.0.client_certificate
  sensitive = true
}

output "kube_config" {
  value     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.dk_dev_cluster.kube_config_raw
  sensitive = true
}

output "aks_lb_public_ip" {
  value     = azurerm_public_ip.lb_pub_ip.ip_address
  sensitive = false
}

output "node_resource_group" {
  value     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.dk_dev_cluster.node_resource_group
  sensitive = false
}

# Create a kubeconfig file that can be added to/replace ~/.kube/config
resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  filename = "kubeconfig"
  content  = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.dk_dev_cluster.kube_config_raw
}
```

Nginx ingress can then be installed using:

````bash
```shell
NAMESPACE=ingress-nginx
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
--create-namespace \
--namespace $NAMESPACE \
--set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz \
--set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=<PUBLIC_IP>
````

Answer (score 0):

I have followed below steps to create application with **Nginx Ingress Controller in AKS Cluster**

> When the look at services in the `nginx-ingress` namespace the LoadBalacer external IP is stuck as `<pending>`

If **Load Balacer** external **IP** is stuck **as pending** state cause of below reasons. follow [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75154385/aks-loadbalancer-external-ip-stuck-on-pending/75159961#75159961) for more details.

1. Insufficient permission in service principal.
2. Make sure you have sufficient quota to provision **Public IPs** in the particular region.

You can assign **Service Principal** using below code.

```
data "azuread_service_principal" "samplesp" {
  display_name  = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes_cluster[0].name
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "akssp_network_contributor_subnet" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subnet.aks-subnet.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_service_principal.aks-sp.object_id

  depends_on = [data.azuread_service_principal.aks-sp]
}
```

Once complete the **AKS Cluster** provisioning, I have deployed an application in **AKS Cluster** using **Nginx Ingress** Service.

To check the application created with **Ingress Controller** use below command.

[image]

When I try to access the application using **Public IP**, its running successfully as below.

[image]

Refer:  [Kubernetes Ingress with NGINX Ingress Controller](https://spacelift.io/blog/kubernetes-ingress) created by @Jack Roper

Comment: I was able to get Nginx to use an existing LB without adding an additional Service Principal. I think service principal & custom vnet is required if using `Azure` network instead of `kubenet`

Please see my answer below